# How to customize code chunks in the "Insert Any" in Quarto documents?

Tags: rstudio, quarto

In Visual mode in Quarto documents in RStudio, there are many useful shortcuts to inserting code chuncks using the *Insert any* menu.

How can I make my own customized code chunks (or blocks) available in the *Insert Any* shortcut? If it is possible to add options to the "insert any" list, where are these templates stored?

[image: RStudio_insert_any]